# A trigonometric equation with many cases

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have to solve the equation $4\cos^m(x)+3\sin^n(x)=5 $ where $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers.  So here comes my question:  The case $m=n=0$ is trivial.  The case $m=n=1$ is easy to solve.  We can divide the equation with 3 and we get $\frac{4}{3}\cos(x)+\sin(x)=\frac{5}{3}$.  There exists an unique angle $t$ in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ such that $\tan(t)=\frac{4}{3}$.  Then we substitute it in the equation and multiplying with $\cos(t)$ we get $\sin(t+x)=\frac{5}{3}\cos(t)$. From $1+\tan^2(t)=\frac{1}{\cos^2(t)}$, we obtain, that $\cos(t)=\frac{3}{5}$ so the equation rewrites as $\sin(x+t)=1$ which is easy to solve.  Now, how with the next cases?

Comment: No, I didn't. The equation rewrites as $sin(x)cos(t)+sin(t)cos(x)=1$

Comment: I really want to see a complete solution!

Comment: I've deleted my comment above.  I now see that from $\frac{4}{3}\cos(x)+\sin(x)=\frac{5}{3}$, you went to $\tan(t)\cos(x)+\sin(x)=\frac{5}{3}$ then multiplied with $\cos(t)$ to get $\sin(t)\cos(x)+\sin(x)\cos(t)=\frac{5}{3}\cos(t)$.

Comment: Taking $\displaystyle m=0,$ we have $\displaystyle\sin^nx=\frac13$ which is always solvable for $n>0$  For $m=n=2,4\cos^2x+3\sin^2x=\cos^2x+3\le4$

Comment: Great! That's the point! There are more ways to solve that equation. What about the next cases? I don't want to miss one of them.( @JoelReyesNoche)

Answer (score 0):

$$3\sin^mx+4cos^nx\le3|\sin^mx|+4|\cos^nx|$$
$$\le 3|\sin x| + 4|\cos x|=5$$
The last inequality assumes that $m,n\ge1$.
Now, if $n\ge 2$, equality in $|\sin^nx|\le|\sin x|$ is achieved iff $|\sin x|=1$ or $|\sin x|=0$. Since the solutions of  $3|\sin x|+4|\cos|=5$ imply that neither condition is met, we actually have for $n\ge 2$ or $m \ge 2$

$$3\sin^mx+4\cos^nx<5$$
So $m=n=1$. The rest is easy.